# 2-column LaTeX environment table* in kable, kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I would like include a wider table in a two column LaTeX article. This could be
achieved in LaTeX using `\begin{table*} ... \end{table*}` instead of
`\begin{table} ... \end{table}`. How can I tell the R packages **kable** or **kableExtra** to
achieve this?

The following produced the usual `\begin{table}`:

```r
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(cars, 1), format = "latex") %>% 
  kable_styling()
```

which produces:

```r
#> \begin{table}[H]
#> \centering
#> \begin{tabular}{r|r}
#> \hline
#> speed & dist\\
#> \hline
#> 4 & 2\\
#> \hline
#> \end{tabular}
#> \end{table}
```

But what I want instead is the following:

```r
#> \begin{table*}[H]
#> \centering
#> \begin{tabular}{r|r}
#> \hline
#> speed & dist\\
#> \hline
#> 4 & 2\\
#> \hline
#> \end{tabular}
#> \end{table*}
```

I am aware that I could use `gsub` to hack the output, but wonder if there is
way to do it cleanly.

Created on 2018-05-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue and even added a feature request to knitr for this, before [Yihui Xie told me](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1585#issuecomment-410922084) that it is already possible to do:

Simply add `table.env='table*'` as an argument to kable:

```
knitr::kable(head(cars,1), format = "latex", table.env='table*')
```

will produce

```
\begin{table*}

  \begin{tabular}{r|r}
    \hline
    speed & dist\\
    \hline
    4 & 2\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `latex_table_env` in `kable_styling`

```
library(kableExtra)
kable(head(cars, 1), format = "latex") %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_table_env = "table*")
```

Comment: This switches `tabular` to `table*`, and I am loosing the floating environment.

Comment: @chris Ah, I see.. Emm, unfortunately, right now there is no way to change that in kableExtra. You will have to do it through gsub.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible with knitr, but it is easily achieved using `xtable` instead:

```
data(cars)
library(xtable)
library(magrittr)

xtable(head(cars, 1), align="rr|r") %>%
  print.xtable(
    floating.environment="table*", # use table* environment
    include.rownames=FALSE,
    table.placement="H"
  )

# % latex table generated in R 3.4.4 by xtable 1.8-2 package
# % Sat May  5 16:47:49 2018
# \begin{table*}[H]
# \centering
# \begin{tabular}{r|r}
#   \hline
# speed & dist \\ 
#   \hline
# 4.00 & 2.00 \\ 
#   \hline
# \end{tabular}
# \end{table*}
```